# Argparse module with multiple command and arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to parse commands with arguments using the python 3 Built-in argparse module.
I have read the [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) partially, however, I could not find anything that meets my requirements.
I parse the arguments as input (I have my reasons).
I have multiple commands, for each, there are both essential and optional arguments.

For example:

`restart --name` (the name is replaced)

`restart` is the command and `name` is the essential argument.

Currently my code would count the "--" in the input and call the function with corresponding booleans (if `--all` given, `is_all` boolean parameter will be true)

I can also add an optional argument `--all` (all is not replaced).

Comment: Please show us some code so that we can help you better

Comment: I don't have any, I recently learned about this module.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I parse the arguments as input"?

Comment: What code would you use *without* `argparse`?

Comment: I'm parsing the input from the user, not the command line arguments.

Comment: I Just did many if elif elses

Comment: The documentation has a handful of examples. When you will get back is a `Namespace` object which contains the parsed results as attributes. The package saves you from doing all those `if`...`elif`...`else` to check the arguments.

Comment: As far as parsing the input for command options, it's also in the documentation. `parser.parse_args(input_line.split())`, where `input_line` is a line you have read from the input.

Comment: I don't have a problem with parsing my input... I've read that already.

Comment: Modules like `argparse` are designed to handle commandline arguments (via `sys.argv`).  They could be used to parse a `input()` string, but that's not common practice.  Beware `argparse` error handling is not designed for interactive use - it usually does a sys.exit.

Comment: `ipython` does use a modified `argparse` to handle inputs for a lot of its `magic` commands.

Comment: Do you have any other options for me?

Comment: Since it's using `sys.exit()`, we can trap the `SystemExit` exception in this unusual use case. If the authors of *argparse* used `os._exit()` there would be no way to trap the forced quit.  I just tested it with "ls --help" with a snippet and was able to continue running. (It does write the help message to stderr)

Comment: It's perfect! the message about what is happenning still printed even though I catch the sys.ext.

Comment: You can also change the `parser.error` and `parser.exit` methods.  Those are documented (briefly)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for something like this

```
def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--arg1", required=False, default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--arg2", required=False, default=None)
    return parser.parse_args()

args = get_arguments()

if args.arg1:
    # do something
```

Really hard to answer this without seeing your code or example of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing something like a shell of sorts. I'm going to also assume that each line entered has a command, each with their own arguments.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def get_parser(cmd):
    '''Returns a parser object for a given command'''
    # Instantiate the parser object, add the appropriate arguments for the command
    return parser  # This is an example -- you need to instantiate it

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            in_line = input('> ')
            if not in_line.strip():  # Quit if empty
                break
            args = in_line.split()
            parser = get_parser(args[0])
            opts = parser.parser_args(args)
            # Do stuff with opts depending on command
        except EOFError:
            break
        except SystemExit:
            pass  # Prevent failures from killing the program by trapping sys.exit()
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like shell, but the part I stuck in is for example I have the command "ls", It will not be a command rather an argument, and for ls there are optional argument such as -l. How do I parse it? I you could write an example.

Comment: Hmm. I think you need to provide examples beyond the "ls" part. In other words, if you pass a list of strings to argparse, it will treat it as if it were parsing through command arguments. It may just be a matter of partitioning your input so that you can treat that "ls" part as if it were a command. Then you can work with that list of arguments including the "ls". I think it depends on how you design your input.

Comment: I just gave a generic example of Unix-like operating system command "ls".

Comment: So am I correct in assuming the user is just going to type "ls" with its options? Then this should take care of it, provided you set up the ArgumentParser with the required and optional arguments.